# How can I call a C function from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm trying to figure out how to call a c function from an obj-c file. I've seen some good examples of how to do the opposite.

In the example below I have an objective c file. It contains a c function named setup.
I want to be able to create an instance of my obj-c file in the regular way and then call the setup function.

### Header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void setup(int,float);

@interface Test : NSObject {
}

@end
```

### Source

```
#import "Test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setup(int val1,float val2)
{
    //do something with values  
}

@implementation Test

@end
```

### View did load

```
Test *test =[Test alloc]init]

//this does not work
test.setup(6,1.4);
```

Comment: What's wrong with using an `init` function to set up your object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call setup(). As declared, is in no way tied to an object - it's just a regular C function.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance but lets say I had a struct in test called myStruct how could I ensure that calling setup would operate on that structs values? Would I have to pass an actual pointer to that struct to the setup function or something?

Comment: Yes, you would. C is still C in the land of objects.